# PHP renaming string if string already exists

Tags: php

I am storing some data in an array and I want to add the key to it if the title already exists in the array. But for some reason it's not adding the key to the title.

Here's my loop:

```
$data = [];

foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
  $local = [];
  $html = file_get_contents($url);
  $crawler = new Crawler($html);
  $headers = $crawler->filter('h1.title');
  $title = $headers->text();
  $lowertitle = strtolower($title);

  if (in_array($lowertitle, $local)) {
    $lowertitle = $lowertitle.$key;
  }

  $local = [
    'title' => $lowertitle,
  ];

  $data[] = $local;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've tried setting `error_reporting(-1);` but I get no errors whatsoever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not find anything here:

```
foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
  $local = [];

  // $local does not change here...

  // So here $local is an empty array
  if (in_array($lowertitle, $local)) {
    $lowertitle = $lowertitle.$key;
  }

  ...
```

If you want to check if the title already exists in the `$data` array, you have a few options:

- You loop over the whole array or use an array filter function to see if the title exists in `$data`;
- You use the lowercase title as the key for your `$data` array. That way you can easily check for duplicate values.

I would use the second option or something similar to it.

A simple example:

```
if (array_key_exists($lowertitle, $data)) {
  $lowertitle = $lowertitle.$key;
}
...
$data[$lowertitle] = $local;
```

Comment: I've tried the same if with the $data array but still nothing happens :/

Comment: @FrankLucas The `$data` array is a multi-dimensional array so you cannot use `in_array` like that to look for a string.

Comment: oh okay I see why do you do this `$data[$lowertitle] = $local;`

Comment: I'm sorry but I am a bit confused, there is no $lowertitle key in my $data array there is 'title' and the value is $lowertitle I'll update OP with a dump of $data

Comment: @FrankLucas The idea behind the code / my answer is to use the title as the main key for `$data` so that you can easily search for it. Using for example `array_key_exists()`.

Comment: I understand, but I don't understand this line `$data[$lowertitle] = $local;`

Comment: @FrankLucas I don't think you do: That is where I add the element to the array and set the key...

Comment: @FrankLucas Just give it a try and check the `var_dump($data);` to see the result.

Comment: I see what happens now, but I don't want that line added to my $data array since I do a json_encode($data); is there a way to remove it after?

Comment: @FrankLucas Sure, you can do an `$data = array_values($data);` at the end (before the json_encode...) to get an array that is compatible with a javascript array. It will replace all keys with numerical ones.

Comment: wauw I feel so stupid what exactly do you mean at the end?

Comment: @FrankLucas Just check the results :-)